# how to change default image in MKUserLocation annotation in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have a map view in my app that displays the user's location. when the user's location is tapped an image is displayed as below:

[image]

is there a way to make this image customized to my liking, so for instance I would like to show the photo that the user has in his own profile, or any other static image that I would like to add.

similar to how the apple maps would show your profile picture in your location dot.

how can I do that here?

here is my code:

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
       if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        print("user location image tapped")
        
           return nil
       }

       let reuseId = "pin"
       var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
       if pinView == nil {
           pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
           pinView?.animatesDrop = true
           pinView?.canShowCallout = true
           pinView?.isDraggable = true
        
         //  pinView?.pinColor = .purple

           let rightButton: AnyObject! = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.detailDisclosure)
           pinView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton as? UIView
   
       }
       else {
           pinView?.annotation = annotation
       }
       
       return pinView
   }
```

any help on this? thank you.

Comment: did you write yourself or copy somewhere ? don't take me wrong but there are some nil control which I have no idea, can you explain more detai. why did you use MKPinAnnotation rather than MKAnnotationView ?

Comment: because with MKPinAnnotation i can have pop up's that view more details to the user which MKAnnotationView  does not support. but that's not at issue here, what do you not understand in my question?@sekoyaz

Comment: hmm then try this one, I m adding to answer it would be helpful @mike

Answer (score 0):

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(0, 0, 25, 25))
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "userpic");
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.layer.frame.size.width / 2
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
anotationView.frame = imageView.frame
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but when i try this it tells me that anotation has no member frame

Comment: annotation view has frame my friend and default is 0 :l

Comment: where would i put the above code, in my code segment? because it is showing me errors and saying it doesn't have a frame. are you coding in general or are you coding this in the scope of my mapView func?

Comment: yeah thats the problem, where should i put the above code? i have several mapview functions, where would i put this code to achieve what i require? thank you

Comment: i am doing it this  way, please check my edited question

Comment: can you please delete your answer? as it doesn't answer my question and now i am unable to delete my question. kindly delete this answer as it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: no i still cant even if i accept. if you would delete it i could